# Trying to create effect where a collection view slides over another collection view on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have two collection views, layered one on top of the other in my ViewController. The collection view on top is a horizontal scrolling collection view, while the one underneath scrolls vertically. I'm trying to create an effect where scrolling the lower collection view will cause it to move upwards to cover the upper collection view, like a sort of parallax effect.

I managed to get the effect by pinning both views to the top of the screen and modifying the lower collection view's content inset when scrolling, but this approach means that I cannot interact with the upper collection view, even when it's exposed. I'm looking for either a modification to this method, or a new method, that would allow me to retain this effect as well as interact with the upper collection view. Any suggestions on how to approach this problem? Thanks.

### The code I have at the moment (more or less):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.contentInset.top = max(0, min(tendToSoon.frame.height, -scrollView.contentOffset.y))
}
```

### [Gif example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUHi5.jpg)

### Unscrolled:

[image: Unscrolled]

### Slightly scrolled:

[image: Slightly scrolled]

### More scrolled:

[image: More scrolled]

Comment: to me, it's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Maybe draw a diagram?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add two collectionviews in the view controller and set `contentInset.top` to height of the first colletionview. And `contentOffset.y` to minus value of `contentInset.top`. And `override point(inside:with:)` and return true only if y value is greater than 0.

Make sure the second collectionview's background color is clear.

[image: Scroll CollectionView]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let topCollectionTitle = UILabel()
    let topCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
    let bottomCollectionView = BottomCollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .white

        topCollectionTitle.textAlignment = .center
        topCollectionTitle.text = "Top Collectionview"
        topCollectionTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(topCollectionTitle)

        let topLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        topLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        topLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width / 5, height: 150)
        topLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        topLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        topLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        topCollectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        topCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = topLayout
        topCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        topCollectionView.register(CellHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CellHeader")

        topCollectionView.register(ImgCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ImgCell")
        topCollectionView.delegate = self
        topCollectionView.dataSource = self
        topCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(topCollectionView)

        let bottomLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        bottomLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        bottomLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width / 2, height: 150)
        bottomLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        bottomLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        bottomLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        bottomLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        bottomCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = bottomLayout
        bottomCollectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        bottomCollectionView.register(CellHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CellHeader")
        bottomCollectionView.register(ImgCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ImgCell")
        bottomCollectionView.delegate = self
        bottomCollectionView.dataSource = self
        bottomCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(bottomCollectionView)

        bottomCollectionView.contentInset.top = 200
        bottomCollectionView.contentOffset.y = -200

        topCollectionTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true

        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[topCollectionView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["topCollectionView":topCollectionView]))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[topCollectionTitle(30)][topCollectionView(200)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["topCollectionView":topCollectionView,"topCollectionTitle":topCollectionTitle]))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(10)-[topCollectionTitle]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["topCollectionTitle":topCollectionTitle]))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[bottomCollectionView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["bottomCollectionView":bottomCollectionView]))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[bottomCollectionView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["bottomCollectionView":bottomCollectionView]))

    }
}
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

}
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 25
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImgCell", for: indexPath) as? ImgCell ?? ImgCell()
        cell.imgView.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
            let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CellHeader", for: indexPath) as? CellHeader
            if collectionView == bottomCollectionView {
                header?.titleLbl.text = "Bottom CollectionView"
            }
            return header!
        }
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
}

class ImgCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let imgView = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupViews()
    }
    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = .white

        imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        imgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imgView)
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(5)-[imgView]-(5)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["imgView":imgView]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(5)-[imgView]-(5)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["imgView":imgView]))
    }
}
class CellHeader: UICollectionReusableView {

    let titleLbl = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupViews()
    }
    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = .white

        titleLbl.textAlignment = .center
        titleLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(titleLbl)

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[titleLbl]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["titleLbl":titleLbl]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[titleLbl]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["titleLbl":titleLbl]))
    }
}
class BottomCollectionView:UICollectionView {
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return point.y > 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

- Put two collection view inside one score view and try to generate parallel effect, you can able to achieve this kind of effect. Please find below link for reference.

[Source](https://github.com/Dhaval3110/SwiftDemoProject/tree/master/ParallaxAndScale)

replace header image with your collection view.